# learning structure with Matlab BNT

Tags: matlab, bayesian-networks

I am trying to create my first Bayesian network with data using PC algorithm or any algorithm. 
So i start to load data from a .xlsx file . then I try `pdag = learn_struct_pdag_pc('cond_indep_fisher_z', n, max_fan_in, A, nsamples, alpha);`

A is the data .

but I got the error Error in cond_indep_fisher_z>normcdf (line 73)

So I try `f(X,Y,S) = cond_indep_fisher_z(X,Y,S,  A,nsamples,alpha)` but I got this error "Undefined function or variable 'X'."

My question how can I apply the PC algorithm ?

Thank you .